# New-SMBShare : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, user-accounts

I am creating Shared folder and want to set permissions on it with SharePoint farm account and App_Pool Account as below:

```
$FullAccessAccounts = "domain\farm,domain\app_pool"
$ReadAccount = "domain\account3"

 New-Item $folderpath –type directory
    New-SMBShare –Name "MyFolder" –Path $folderpath –ContinuouslyAvailable $true –FullAccess $FullAccessAccounts -ReadAccess $ReadAccount
```

But i am getting following error, which i could not understand how to solve this?

New-SMBShare : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for the command is very poor concerning the required format for the IDs.  If you modify your example and change the line:

`$FullAccessAccounts = "domain\farm,domain\app_pool"`

to

`$FullAccessAccounts = ("farm","app_pool")`

this will work:

`New-SMBShare –Name "MyFolder" –Path $folderpath –FullAccess $FullAccessAccounts`

Note that you have to omit the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

I found another similar issue.
The group I was try to use with Grant-SmbShareAccess had been renamed in the past.
if I changed the variable to use the Group Name (pre-Windows 2000): value it worked.
we are part of an enterprise domain that has been running since 4.0 days.

Comment: I can't tell if this is commentary or an answer.  If this is an answer, can you update it so that it's a bit more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Also check the accounts being assigned actually exist in the Active Directory, and there are no duplicate entries.

I found this PowerShell useful:

```
$ReadAccessUserList = $ReadAccessUserList | Sort-Object | Select-Object -Unique
```

Easy then to loop through, display the user list about to be implemented, remove any domain references if necessary, etc.